# Python Webdriver : Profile Creation Using Code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

is there any way we can create browser profiles using code? chrome,gecko , brave , edge or any other. want to create profiles using code to save time. i tried looking over internet but couldn't find any solution , thanks

i tried looking over github and stackoverflow but no luck. tried chatgpt too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create chrome profiles using the code below, **just specify the path you want profiles save in & the name of profile** :

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+os.path.abspath('Profiles/Jason')) # Put were you want save created profiles
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions-file-access-check")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)   
# Your code here
```